# Tsung - testing a proxy server

Tags: tsung

I am trying to load test a proxy server.
I know that I need to add the following command to the TSUNG configuration file:

```
option type="ts_http" name="http_use_server_as_proxy" value="true"
```

However, I am not sure where in the xml configuration file this option should be entered.
Any example of a TSUNG XML configuration file that load test a proxy server would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this option before  in xml:

```
.......
  <options>
    <option name="exampleName" id='exampleID' value="path to csv>
    <option type="ts_http" name="http_use_server_as_proxy" value="true">
     ......
    </option>
  </options>

  <sessions>
    <session name="example" probability="100" type="ts_http">
    ......
  </sessions>
......
```

also you can read examples , there -> https://github.com/processone/tsung/tree/master/examples